# (JS) - Error while accessing stomp (socket) in my html page through scripts

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot, websocket

```
Spring Boot WebSocket Example










    
    
    
    Send

<ul></ul>

    var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    function connectAndSendMessage(message) {
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/user/topic/messages', function (message) {
                showMessage(JSON.parse(message.body).content);
            });

            // Send the message after successfully reconnecting
            stompClient.send("/app/chat/send", {}, JSON.stringify(message));
        });
    }
    function sendMessage() {
        var sender = document.getElementById('sender').value;
        var receiver = document.getElementById('receiver').value;
        var content = document.getElementById('content').value;
        var message = {
            sender: sender,
            receiver: receiver,
            content: content
        };

        // Check if stompClient is connected before sending a message
        if (stompClient.connected) {
            stompClient.send("/app/chat/send", {}, JSON.stringify(message));
        } else {
            // If not connected, attempt to connect and send the message
            connectAndSendMessage(message);
        }
    }

    function showMessage(message) {
        var ul = document.getElementById('messages');
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
</script>
```

Just after launching the project in locally , which is a module for chat, in my frontend, i am receiving an error while inspecting the html page given above.
fyi, i wrote an spring boot application  which replica a chat/message section of it.

Error encounting,

GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:11
GET http://localhost:8080/stomp.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

(index):23 Uncaught ReferenceError: Stomp is not defined
at (index):23:27

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the link `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js` is correct? The reason - opening it via the browser, or fetching it via cURL (Windows) returns 404.